# Can I trigger a DAG w/ config on a specific date and a task who run another dag keep the same date?

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Im Triggering a dag with a specific date (2022-09-20)

[image]

The dag run on that date with no problem, but I want the task called "run_biopackaging" to execute with the same date given by the trigger. "run_biopackaging" is on another dag, so is executed with "today's date"

[image]

Is there a method to tun the second dag with the date I gave to the trigger?

I want run_biopackaging to be executed on the date given by the trigger, in this case is 2022-09-20

[image]